# Deserializing this object in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have the following object:

```
{
    "pickups": {
        "7": [
            5,
            8
        ],
        "10": [
            6,
            7,
            9
        ],
        "15": [
            1
        ],
        "20": [
            0,
            2
        ],
        "25": [
            3,
            4
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to de-serialize each pickups element into the following object:

```
public class Pickups {
    public Pickup[] pickups;
}

public class Pickup {
    public int Group; // This could be the 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc.
    public int[] Values; // If this was the "7" grouping, it would contain 5, 8.
}
```

As you can see from the data its a bit tricky to do this. I've been trying to use a [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to convert the object with a bit of custom code but its been a nightmare and I haven't been able to get it right. I am wondering if anyone would know the best way to convert this type of object into the correct format I need?

Comment: You JSON says you have a pickup object with properties of 7, 10, 15 etc. Do you have control over this JSON?

Comment: @Blast_dan I don't have control over the JSON format, unfortunately

Comment: Could you share your JsonConverter?

Comment: Looks like you're going to need to write your own custom `public class PickupConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Pickup> {...} ` converter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While a converter would be a good choice you can still deserialize the Json and construct the desired object graph

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var pickups = new Pickups {
    pickups = root.pickups.Select(kvp =>
        new Pickup {
            Group = int.Parse(kvp.Key),
            Values = kvp.Value
        }
    ).ToArray()
};
```

Where

```
public class RootObject {
    public IDictionary<string, int[]> pickups { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what [son2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) says, its gets error because you can not define names with starting number.

```
public class Pickups
{
    public List<int> __invalid_name__7 { get; set; }
    public List<int> __invalid_name__10 { get; set; }
    public List<int> __invalid_name__15 { get; set; }
    public List<int> __invalid_name__20 { get; set; }
    public List<int> __invalid_name__25 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Pickups pickups { get; set; }
}
```

But I think

```
[DataMember(Name = "Name")]
```

should work cause its not an error in JSON format side.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a viable option for you to use JObject.Parse(...) instead, you could use the following code (and write it more cleanly, with exception handling and safe casts and so on):

```
var jsonPickups = JObject.Parse(json);
var myPickups = new Pickups
{
    pickups = jsonPickups.First.First.Select(x =>
    {
        JProperty xProp = x as JProperty;
        return new Pickup
        {
            Group = int.Parse(xProp.Name),
            Values = (xProp.Value as JArray).Select(y => int.Parse(y.ToString())).ToArray()
        };
    }).ToArray()
};
```